# Linux Encrypted Backup solution to USB HD (Open Source)

Tags: linux, hard-drive, usb, backup

There are a lot of backup solutions, many scripts based of rsync.  The problem is not a lot of them encrypt your data before syncing it.  I have a USB hard drive and I want to backup my user folder /home/myuser/ to the external drive.  What software will allow me to create incremental backups which are encrypted with relative ease

Comment: I know this is an old question, but for anyone looking at this,  you might want to look at [borg backup](https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Comment: The stack exchange sites are totally open to commenting on updating older questions. The intent is for these questions to he searchable like a wiki. You may want to add a little more to your comment as to what that program offers/why you think it's a good option for this case. Thanks for contributing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use full disk encryption on the disk?  It'll be transparent to rsync, but your data will be encrypted.  Here's [how to do it](http://earlruby.org/2010/02/adding-an-external-encrypted-drive-with-lvm-to-ubuntu-linux/).

Comment: This is amazing!

Answer (score 1):

Try [Duply](http://duply.net/). It's commonly used over ftp but it also has a file:/// backup target scheme.

Comment: Duply works, but it's still somewhat clumsy.